# PlaneBufferGeometry: change its vertex coordinates origin

Tags: three.js

I have a PlaneBufferGeometry and its vertex origin is the center of the object, but I'd like to move it to the top left vertex. Is there a function or do I have to create it?

Comment: Is `geometry.translate( width / 2, - height / 2, 0 );` what you are looking for?

Comment: Or `geometry.translate(geometry.parameters.width / 2, -geometry.parameters.height / 2, 0);` [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/vnunzaxo/)

Comment: Oh yes! That helps! Thanks! Put it as an answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can translate your geometry using the following pattern:

```
geometry.translate( x, y, z );
```

three.js r.84